# SQL Full Outer Join : Whats the difference in these queries?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Lets suppose I have a full outer join query written in these styles:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B ON (Table_A.Col1 = Table_B.Col1 AND Table_B.iscurrent=1)
```

Versus

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A
FULL OUTER JOIN (Select * FROM Table_B Where iscurrent=1) AS Table_B
ON (Table_A.Col1 = Table_B.Col1)
```

Both are producing different results in my database (Azure SQL DB).

How come?

Comment: The Derived Table in your 2nd Select reduces the number of rows *before* the join.

Comment: The first one only makes the join where Table_B.iscurrent=1 but will return all the data available on the records that dont join - The second one only joins a subset of table B , thus reducing the records available to return on all lines

Comment: To my eye they should produce the same results. Try ordering the results of both queries by the primary key on TABLE_A and see what you get.

Comment: @BobJarvis: It's a Full Outer Join without any additional conditions, of course the result will change when you join less rows from TableB.

Answer (score 0):

Why are they returning different results?  Because they are different queries.  `FULL OUTER JOIN` is very tricky.  Let me explain.

The result set from the first query has rows from *all* the rows in both tables, even those where `Table_B.iscurrent <> 1`.  If this is not true, then the corresponding columns will be `NULL`, but the row will be there.

The result set from the second query will have no rows were `Table_B.iscurrent <> 1`.  These are filtered out *before* the `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so they are not among the rows being counted.

In general, I find that `FULL OUTER JOIN` is very rarely needed.  I do use it, but quite rarely.  Typically `LEFT JOIN` or `UNION ALL` does what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

On the second only rows with Where Table_B.iscurrent = 1 are included.

In the first you have all the rows in Table_B but they just don't connect to Table_A if iscurrent <> 1.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B 
  ON Table_A.Col1 = Table_B.Col1 
 AND Table_B.iscurrent = 1

SELECT * 
FROM Table_A
FULL OUTER JOIN ( Select * 
                  FROM Table_B 
                  Where iscurrent = 1
                ) AS Table_B
  ON Table_A.Col1 = Table_B.Col1
```